# MongoDB optimize multiple find_one + insert inside loop

Tags: python, mongodb, optimization, pymongo

I'm using MongoDB 4.0.1 and Pymongo with pyhton 3.5. I have to loop over 12000 items every 30 - 60 seconds and add new data into MongoDB. For this example we will talk about User, Pet and Car. The User can get 1 Car and 1 Pet.

I need the pet ObjectID and the car ObjectID to create my User so I have to add them one by one in the loop and this is very slow. It takes ~25 seconds to find existing data and add them if the data not exist.

```
while dictionary != False:
    # Create pet if not exist
    existing_pet = pet.find_one({"code": dictionary['pet_code']})

    if bool(existing_pet):
        pet_id = existing_pet['_id']
    else:
        pet_id = pet.insert({
            "code" : dictionary['pet_code'],
            "name" : dictionary['name']
        })
        # Call web service to create pet remote

    # Create car if not exist
    existing_car = car.find_one({"platenumber": dictionary['platenumber']})

    if bool(existing_car):
        car_id = existing_car['_id']
    else:
        car_id = car.insert({
            "platenumber" : dictionary['platenumber'],
            "model" : dictionary['model'],
            "energy" : 'electric'
        })
        # Call web service to create car remote

    # Create user if not exist
    existing_user = user.find_one(
        {"$and": [
            {"user_code": dictionary['user_code']},
            {"car": car_id},
            {"pet": pet_id}
        ]}
    )

    if not bool(existing_user):
        user_data.append({
            "pet" : pet_id,
            "car" : car_id,
            "firstname" : dictionary['firstname'],
            "lastname" : dictionary['lastname']
        })
        # Call web service to create user remote

# Bulk insert user
if user_data:
    user.insert_many(user_data)
```

I created indexes for each column used for the find_one :

```
db.user.createIndex( { user_code: 1 } )
db.user.createIndex( { pet: 1 } )
db.user.createIndex( { car: 1 } )
db.pet.createIndex( { pet_code: 1 }, { unique: true }  )
db.car.createIndex( { platenumber: 1 }, { unique: true }  )
```

There is a way to speed up this loop ? There is something with aggregation or other things to help me ? Or maybe another way to do what I want ?

I'm open for all advices.

Comment: Don´t do 12000 find_one queries, do 1 query to bring all that exist with $in operator

Comment: Can you give me an example how you can do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don´t do 12000 find_one queries, do 1 query to bring all that exist with $in operator. Code would be something like:

```
pet_codes = []
pet_names = []
while dictionary != False:
    pet_codes.append(dictionary['pet_code'])
    pet_names.append(dictionary['pet_name'])

pets = dict()
for pet in pet.find({"code": {$in: pet_codes}}):
    pets[pet['code']] = pet

new_pets = []
for code, name in zip(pet_codes, pet_names):
    if code not in pets:
        new_pets.add({'pet_code': code, 'name': name})

pet.insert_many(new_pets)
```

As you already have an index on pet_code making it unique, we can do better: just try to insert them all, because if we try to insert an existing one that record will get an error, but the rest will succeed by using the ordered=False from [the docs](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_many):

```
new_pets = []
while dictionary != False:
    new_pets.add({
        "code" : dictionary['pet_code'],
        "name" : dictionary['name']
    })
pet.insert_many(new_pets, ordered=False)
```

In the case where you do not have a unique restriction set, another method is [batching the operations](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html)

Comment: I have a problem with that because I lost the pet relation with his User. I have to put the Pet object id in my User when I create it

Comment: @John you can query the records after the insert to get all the pet_ids

Comment: So the find_one will be faster that the insert ? And I will loop over the same dictionary twice ? First for insert then another time for find the item ?

Comment: @John dont use find_one, use find to fetch all with the same query, as in my first example

Comment: In fact, your answer don't resolve my problem :/. I don't want to add all properties object into different array. Each object has at least 7 properties. Try to do with you solution what I'm doing with all objects (pet, car and user) you will see it will not working. And I don't know how to query all my insterted ids for each object to populate user object and call web service for each object

Comment: @John yes, an array for each object property that you need to query works fine. insert_many returns an array of the inserted document ids... anyway wasn´t this resolved already in your other question?

Comment: This question is different of my other

Comment: @John can use same answer as the other, make queries for the stuff you need with $or operator to bring all in 1 query, and then for missing ones call web service + insert them all

Comment: I tried to use the same answer as the other but I don't know how to loop on the news inserted data to add one by one using web service. Can you try to show me with the code ?

Comment: @John do print of insert_many result, you will see inserted ids there

Comment: Ok so I adapted this script by using the other way. It's reaaaaally slow at the first insert, because I have lot of items to insert but it's a scheduler so this script is called every 30 sec, so after I add 1 to 5 data max so it's ok. And I don't have memory leak problem after 2 days

Comment: I created pastebin link : https://pastebin.com/EtT9pm9U you can see my code. I tried to put all find out of the loop. But there is on `find_one` inside user loop that I don't know how to delete.

Comment: @John use $or to make all queries at once https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/

Comment: I tried but I don't know where I have to use this. Can you edit my script and show me ?

Comment: this is not what I need. I need to insert_many all users who are not in mongo. Your $or condition will return all users in my database. That is why I do a if condition with not in find one

Comment: @John I won´t code the whole example for you... it won´t return all users, it will return all matching users for the or conditions. You can then for each user in user_data, check if its inside the set of users returned by the query

Comment: I think I don't explain correctly what I want. But mongo condition will not help me I think. I created a new SO question to add to another list all users who are not in mongo here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52834594/python-multiple-condition-between-two-list#52834594 and now it works