# Python multiple condition between two list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm using python 3 and I need to check 3 variables in different list. I want to print data if `username` `age` `lang` are different from the other list

Here is my code :

```
list1 = []
list2 = []

list1.append({'username' : 'alice', 'age' : 25, 'lang' : 'IT'})
list1.append({'username' : 'carole', 'age' : 40, 'lang' : 'FR'})
list1.append({'username' : 'john', 'age' : 30, 'lang' : 'FR'})
list1.append({'username' : 'mick', 'age' : 20, 'lang' : 'US'})
list1.append({'username' : 'mick', 'age' : 30, 'lang' : 'US'})

list2.append({'username' : 'mick-c', 'age' : 30, 'lang' : 'US'})
list2.append({'username' : 'john', 'age' : 30, 'lang' : 'FR'})
list2.append({'username' : 'john-b', 'age' : 30, 'lang' : 'FR'})

for l1 in list1:
    username = l1['username']
    age = l1['age']
    lang = l1['lang']

    for l2 in list2:
        if username not in l2['username'] and l2['age'] != age and l2['lang'] != lang:
            print(str(username) + ' ' + str(age) + ' ' + str(lang))
```

Output :

```
alice 25 IT
alice 25 IT
alice 25 IT
carole 40 FR
mick 20 US
mick 20 US
```

And my expected output was :

```
alice 25 IT
carole 40 FR
mick 20 US
```

How can I do to not have duplicated data in the loop ? And there is another way to do what I want instead of use double loops ?

Comment: You can use `break` in your second for loop

Comment: @Bazingaa Oh yeah it works ty

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: What happened to mick aged 30?

Comment: @jpp this mick is ignored because there is mick-b in the other list. And in my test I want to ignore -b that is why I'm using `if username not in l2['username']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set` to hash a sequence of `tuple` elements from one list. The logic below works specifically when names are in `list2` can be of the format `name-a`, `name-b`, etc, and you are only interested in the first part.

```
from operator import itemgetter

def field_getter(x):
    i, j, k = itemgetter('username', 'age', 'lang')(x)
    return i.split('-')[0], j, k

item_set = set(map(field_getter, list2))

for d in list1:
    d_fields = field_getter(d)
    if field_getter(d) not in item_set:
        print(*d_fields)

alice 25 IT
carole 40 FR
mick 20 US
```

Comment: Very pretty code ! I don't understand all but thanks.

Comment: There is a way to make it work if the list1 and list2 have different key ? example list1 has `username` and list2 `name`

Comment: @John, You have to define *carefully* "different key". My solution only works if `list2` names are of the format `name-a`. You can modify / change the logic yourself by changing the line `return i.split('-')[0], j, k`.

Comment: It's ok for `name-a`. The problem is just for the key. Where I have to define different key ? Test it : https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/ad2c4bf4-ddff-4860-9ee1-b8eeb00a23fe/?i=true

Comment: @John, Then define 2 `field_getter` functions, you can call them `field_getter_1` and `field_getter_2`. Use the appropriate names in each function. Or, better, take the field names as an argument. Too much for a comment, if you're stuck feel free to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Thank you it works : https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/ad2c4bf4-ddff-4860-9ee1-b8eeb00a23fe/?i=true

Answer (score 1):

You should output the record only if it's not found in `list2`, so you should use the `for-else` construct to `print` after you've made sure there's no entry in `list2` with all 3 fields passing the equality tests (rather than inequality tests):

```
for l1 in list1:
    username = l1['username']
    age = l1['age']
    lang = l1['lang']

    for l2 in list2:
        if username in l2['username'] and l2['age'] == age and l2['lang'] == lang:
            break
    else:
        print(str(username) + ' ' + str(age) + ' ' + str(lang))
```

This outputs:

```
alice 25 IT
carole 40 FR
mick 20 US
```

Comment: Yes, I was simply trying to point out the issue with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the items with a comparison rule on the three fields. The identical records will appear next to each other and a single loop will be enough.

Comment: Just a single loop ? Can you show me how you do this ?

Comment: @John: compare the pairs of consecutive elements.

{'username' : 'alice', 'age' : 25, 'lang' : 'IT'}

{'username' : 'carole', 'age' : 40, 'lang' : 'FR'}

{'username' : 'john', 'age' : 30, 'lang' : 'FR'}

{'username' : 'john', 'age' : 30, 'lang' : 'FR'}

{'username' : 'john-b', 'age' : 30, 'lang' : 'FR'}

{'username' : 'mick', 'age' : 20, 'lang' : 'US'}

{'username' : 'mick', 'age' : 30, 'lang' : 'US'}

{'username' : 'mick-c', 'age' : 30, 'lang' : 'US'}

Comment: I'm not sure this would work, note it searches for names _contained_ in one another, not necessarily identical ones.

Comment: @jdehesa: the comparison function can integrate that requirement.